# How to subclip specified number of frames in a VideoFileClip in Moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm looking for a way to remove some frames of video or cut some sequences of video clips and then concatenate them. Is there any way to do so in Moviepy?

I know one possible solution is to compute the duration of each frame based on the fps of the video and use it as a time unit in the `subclip` method of the `VideoFileClip` object, but it's not too accurate and there are some situations that the result is not correct.

```py
clip = VideoFileClip('sample.mp4')
fps = clip.fps
frame_duration = 1 / fps
# subclip from second frame to fifth frame
clip.subclip(t_start=2*frame_duration, t_end=5*frame_duration)
```

Comment: Here's how moviepy converts the time you give it into a frame number: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/db19920764b5cb1d8aa6863019544fd8ae0d3cce/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py#L169 Some testing finds it's consistently one frame too high.

Comment: thanks @NickODell, you're right. I think it could be ok if in the worst case a frame is missed. but I still wonder why moviepy doesn't have such a subclip method to do this on the sequence of frames rather than time intervals. do you have any idea?

Comment: I also came across the same issue. The number of frames is correct but each video is about 0.02 seconds longer. There doesn't seem to be a bug lugged for this?!

Comment: Did you check the frame rate? I'm not sure Maybe it has been changed.